# Linear Performance Scalability with HP San Solutions

Tags: storage-area-network, hp, lefthand, hp-modular-smart-array

I need a San Solution with linear scalability in size as well as in performance.

From what I know, with a Modular Smart Array solution such as the P2000/MSA-class solutions from HP, even with a dual controller initial node, I can only increase the size of it, as added nodes come controller-less, so overall performance tends to decrease.

On the other hand, the P4000 (lefthand) family of solutions has each of it's nodes have it's own controller, and so when a node is added, storage capacity as well as performance increase.

Am I right in all that I say, and is the P4000 the only solution, or have I forgotten something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't mention which protocols you want to use but for FC the XP range can grow pretty linearly (gets expensive though). I know it's not what you asked for the 9100 EDS stuff is very linear but NAS protocols only.

Answer (score 0):

HP EVA`? ;)

Define SAN Solution. Seriously. I know one EVA I once was connected to giving me 190 SAS discs for a database server. Large enough?

http://h18006.www1.hp.com/storage/disk_storage/eva_diskarrays/index.html

Comment: I love EVAs and use them all over the place but they're quite port-limited even though you can put a fairly decent number of disks in them.